# Rails installation suddenly not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.0.5, and I have this in my `.bash_profile`:

```
 -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Rails was working fine, but suddenly it's not working anymore. How can I get Rails working again?

For reference, here is the output of running `rvm info`:

```
jean@jean-ThinkPad-L430:~/development/public/COPD$ rvm info

ruby-2.1.0:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux jean-ThinkPad-L430 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/14.04/i386"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         "/usr/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.25.25 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "9 hours 56 minutes 27 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/jean/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.1.0p0"
    date:         "2013-12-25"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2013-12-25 revision 44422"
    full_version: "ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0"
    ruby:         "/home/jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/home/jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:/home/jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/jean/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0:/home/jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0"
    IRBRC:        "/home/jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get install ruby-railties-4.0` ?

Comment: yes I have tried it ! there is no package ruby-railsties-4.0

Comment: And the error persisted?

Comment: yes `E: Unable to locate package ruby-railsties-4.0`
`E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby-railsties-4.0'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RVM error with gnome-terminal
```

The answer is documented here https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal

**Guake terminal**
Right-click on the Guake terminal -- choose  -> Preferences => check {Run command as a login shell}

**Ubuntu terminal** => Right click on the terminal => Profiles => Profiles Preferences => [TAB] Title and Command =>  check {Run command as a login shell}

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Papouche's answer executing the following command will do the same thing `bash -l` in the command line